# How to build dev version of angular-cli app

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli, angular2-template

I had an angular click app.I used the command 'ng build --prod' for uploading code into server.This works fine but I am unable to debug my code because of compressed files.Can anyone help me to upload code to server such that I can able to debug it.Thanks.

Comment: u can just omit `--prod` and go with `ng build`, this will not minify the files

Comment: Thank you Dhyey...It worked fine.

Comment: u r wlcm MMR :)

Answer (score 0):

Read at github sources. In this link you can make build with some parameters

try it

```
ng build --prod --env=dev
```

[build doc](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/build.md)